# display wordpress post on remote php website

Tags: php, wordpress, parsing, rss

Hello i have wordpress website i have around 100 post in it and i daily update them

i want to display latest 3 post on remote website is this possible with any rss feed parsing or any other method.I tried with below code but it shows failed

```
<?php 
        $feedUrl = 'http://testserver.com/brand_new/feed';
        $rawFeed = file_get_contents($feedUrl);

        print_r($rawFeed);
        exit;

         $anobii = new SimpleXmlElement($rawFeed);

        foreach ($anobii->channel->item as $anobiiinfo):
            $title=$anobiiinfo->title;
            $desc=$anobiiinfo->description;       
            echo "<span> ",$title,"</span> <br/> <span> ",$desc,"</span>";
        endforeach;
    ?>
```

I tried even with

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://wallpapers.celeborama.net/feed/');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($data);
```

but it shows error as well

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'String could not be parsed as XML' in G:\xampp\htdocs\wpfeed.php:11 Stack trace: #0 G:\xampp\htdocs\wpfeed.php(11): SimpleXMLElement->__construct('') #1 {main} thrown in G:\xampp\htdocs\wpfeed.php on line 11
```

Comment: What does var_dump(htmlentities($data)) says?

Comment: it returns string(0) ""

Comment: is there an alternative way to get wordpress post easily to other remote website?

Comment: Is it normal that there is nothing there : http://wallpapers.celeborama.net/feed/ ?

Comment: Use this codex   http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/fetch_feed.

Comment: This was a good answer, you shouldn't have deleted it.

Comment: HI i need it in reverse order means this function fetch feed will show feed to wordpress website. i want wordpress post to other php based website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordpress provide function to fetch remote data. So you can use that.see below code

```
$feedUrl = 'http://project.demotestserver.com/brand_new/feed';
$data = wp_remote_retrieve_body(wp_remote_get($feedUrl, array( 'timeout' => 30000 ) ));
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML($data);
if (!$dom) {
    echo 'Error while parsing the document';
    exit;
}
$xml = simplexml_import_dom($dom);
$posts = $xml->channel->item;
    $i=0;
    foreach($posts as $key => $post) {
       if($i>=3) continue;
        $title=$post->title;
        $i++;

    }

   print_r($title);
```

Comment: Hello bhumi how will use this code in remote php file  as it contains wordpress function it will show error?

Comment: you load wp-load file of wordpress like require_once($base_dir . "/wp-load.php"); and use this code

Answer (score 0):

Your code works.

```
<?php
$feed = 'http://rss.slashdot.org/Slashdot/slashdot';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $feed);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

//print_r($data);

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($data);
foreach ($xml->channel->item as $i) {
    echo $i->title . PHP_EOL;
}
?>
```

-

```
$ php ~/tmp/so/php-feed/smple.xml.php 
Should Newsweek Have Outed Satoshi Nakamoto's Personal Details?
Stanford Team Tries For Better Wi-Fi In Crowded Buildings
Computer Program Allows the Blind To "See" With Sound
(...)
```

---

Your URL is not working because:

```
$ curl -D-  http://project.demotestserver.com/brand_new/feed 
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
(...)
Location: http://project.demotestserver.com/brand_new/feed/
```

You can check the headers with PHP-curl too, check the docs.

Comment: Hi yes your url works fine with that but when i enter my feed url it shows error here is my url                http://project.demotestserver.com/brand_new/feed

Comment: The URL is missing a slash at the end.